# Difference between async await in python vs JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, asynchronous, async-await

Note: this is not about multi threading or multi processing. This question is regarding a single process and single thread.

Python async.io and JavaScript async both are single thread concepts.

In python, async.io, we can use async await keywords to create a function so that when this function is invoked multiple times (via gather) they get executed concurrently. The way it works is that when an await keyword is encountered, other tasks can execute. As explained here we apply the async await keywords to function that we would like to execute concurrently. However while these tasks are running concurrently, the main thread is blocked.

In JavaScript async has evolved from callbacks, promise, async/await. In the main program, when async is encountered, then the function is sent to the event loop (where the function execution begins) and the main thread can continue working. Any subsequent async function also gets added to the event loop. Inside the event loop when the function execution encountered an await then other function is given a chance to execute untill await in encountered.

To get this behaviour in python, that is - allow main thread to continue while executing child tasks the only option is multithreading/multiprocessing. Because once we start the child thread/process, and untill we call `.join` the main thread is not blocked.

Is there anyway by which the python's async.io can make the main thread non blocking? If not, then is this the fundamental difference between async concept in JavaScript and python?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> when async is encountered, then the function is sent to the event loop and the main thread can continue working.

This is *close*, but not quite right. In Javascript, execution won't stop until the callstack has been emptied - the await keyword will suspend the execution of a particular function until an event triggers, and in the mean time, control returns to its caller. This means the first part of any async function will execute as soon as it is called (it's not immediately put into the event loop), and will only pause as soon as an `await` is hit.

> To get this behaviour in python, that is - allow main thread to continue while executing child tasks the only option is multithreading/multiprocessing.

The difference here is that by default, Javascript always has an event loop and python does not. In other words, python has an on/off switch for asynchronous programming while Javascript does not. When you run something such as `loop.run_forever()`, you're basically flipping the event loop on, and execution won't continue where you left off until the event loop gets turned back off. (calling it a "thread" isn't quite the right word here, as it's all single-threaded, as you already acknowledged. Instead, we generally call each task that we queue up, well, a "task")

You're asking if there's a way to let your code continue execution after starting up the event loop. I'm pretty sure the answer is no, nor should it be needed. Whatever you want to execute after the event loop has started can just be executed within the event loop.

If you want your python program to act more like Javascript, then the first thing you do can be to start up an event loop, and then any further logic can be placed within the first task that the event loop executes. In Javascript, this boiler plate essentially happens for you, and your source code is effectively that first task that's queued up in the event loop.

**Update:**

Because there seems to be some confusion with how the Javascript event loop works, I'll try to explain it a little further.

Remember that an event loop is simply a system where, when certain events happen, a block of synchronous code can be queued up to run as soon as the thread is not busy.

So let's see what the event loop does for a simple program like this:

```js
// This async function will resolve
// after the number of ms provided has passed
const wait = ms => { ... }

async function main() {
  console.log(2)
  await wait(100)
  console.log(4)
}

console.log(1)
main()
console.log(3)
```

When Javascript begins executing the above program, it'll begin with a single task queued up in it's "run these things when you're not busy" queue. This item is the whole program.

So, it'll start at the top, defining whatever needs to be defined, executes `console.log(1)`, call the main function, enters into it and runs `console.log(2)`, calls wait() which will conceptually cause a background timer to start, wait() will return a promise which we then `await`, at which point we immediately go back to the caller of main, main wasn't awaited so execution continues to `console.log(3)`, until we finally finish at the end of the file. That whole path (from defining functions to `console.log(3)`) is a single, non-interruptible task. Even if another task got queued up, Javascript wouldn't stop to handle that task until it finished this chunk of synchronous logic.

Later on, our countdown timer will finish, and another task will go into our queue, which will cause our main() function to continue execution. The same logic as before applies here - our execution path could enter and exit other async functions, and will only stop when it reaches the end of, in this case, the main function (even hitting an await keywords doesn't actually make this line of syncrounous logic stop, it just makes it jump back to the caller). The execution of a single task doesn't stop until the callstack has been emptied, and when execution is continuing from an async function, the first entry of the callstack starts at that particular async function.

Python's async/await follows these same rules, except for the fact that in Python, the event loop isn't running by default.

Comment: I have updated javascript section in my question. Plese can you have a look. Also, originally, in the JavaScript section, I never said that execution will pause until the await keyword is encountered.

Comment: So, the "main" program in Javascript doesn't actually have any special treatment. It's just another task in the event loop. The first line you execute in Javascript would be equivalent to the first line of the first task of a python event loop.

Comment: @variable I updated my answer to try and explain the event loop a little clearer. Hopefully, this can help with some of the confusion.

Comment: Thank you for this. In js, after putting wait in the event loop, control comes back to main. Ok. Question 1: Then when does control goes back to console.log(4)? Is it either after finishing main thread or encountering async keyword in another subsequent function or is there any other possibility? Question 2: can we write await keyword in main program to force control to go to next task?

Comment: 1. The main (initial) task will run to completion and can't be interrupted, as is the case with any other task. The task to finish executing the main() function can happen as soon as the countdown has finished and no other task is currently running. This could be after main() has finished and between awaits of other function calls. 2. Effectivly yes (assuming all the callers in this callstack are also awaiting this promise).

Comment: Scotty, suppose there are 4 tasks in the event loop, and say currently task 1 is executing. As you say, the switch will happen either when task 1 finishes or when it encounters a subsequent async command in task 1. Either ways how does js decide which of the 3 tasks to switch into?

Comment: If I have an async function with two awaits, then in the eyes of the event loop, that's three independent and unrelated tasks. Task 1 is whoever calls the async function, the first part of the async function, and if the caller didn't await the async function, then it'll also include any other code it runs after calling it. Task 2 spans between the two awaits of that async function. Task 3  spans between the second await and the end of the function. The event loop doesn't even know task 2 and 3 will exist until the promises you awaited resolve, at which point the task gets created and queued up

Comment: So, to answer your question, if you're running 1 task and 3 others are queued up, the switch will not happen until task 1 finishes. You can't ever pause a task. `await` pauses a function, and will cause another task to be queued up later that will finish executing the function once a given promise resolves. Once task 1 finishes, it'll execute the next task in the queue, i.e. the task that's been waiting the longest to execute. Once the next task it taken out of the queue, it'll never go back in, but it can cause further tasks to be generated at a later point.

Comment: Here's a good resource that'll explain this all further: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Comment: Hi Scotty, in case of python, if you see the example here https://realpython.com/async-io-python/#the-asyncawait-syntax-and-native-coroutines, it executes the await statements in parallel. Where as in the case of Javascript, await puts the task into the loop and passed control to the caller. Have I understood this difference correctly?

Comment: Let's break that example apart. If you call count() multiple times without await, then you'll start multiple async operations. In that example, count() is called three times (without await), then their promises are passed to asyncio.gather(), which is a special function that creates a new promise that resolves once all of the passed-in promises resolve. Finally, we await this special promise. In other words, we're starting three async tasks at the same time and waiting for them all. (they still take turns, it's not multithreaded). It's the same in Javascript, but we use Promise.all() instead.

Comment: Ok got that now. I was confused on how it could be done in js using async await. Now that you mention promise.all it makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

javascript

```
const wait = async (s) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("wating " + s + "s")
    }, s * 1000)
}
async function read_file() {
    console.log("initial read_file sleep(2.1)")
    await wait(2)
    console.log("read_file 1/2 wait(2)")
    await wait(0.1)
    console.log("read_file 2/2 wait(0.1)")
}
async function read_api() {
    console.log("initial read_api wait(2)")
    await wait(2)
    console.log("read_api whole wait(2)")
}
read_file()
console.log("does not block")
read_api()
console.log("the second time, won't block")
// initial read_file sleep(2.1)
// does not block
// initial read_api wait(2)
// the second time, won't block
// read_file 1/2 wait(2)
// read_api whole wait(2)
// read_file 2/2 wait(0.1)
// !!! Wait a moment
// wating 0.1s
// wating 2s 
// wating 2s
```

python

```
import asyncio

async def read_file():
    print("initial read_file asyncio.sleep(2 + 0.1)")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print("read_file 1/2 asyncio.sleep(2)")
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    print("read_file 2/2 asyncio.sleep(0.1)")

async def read_api():
    print("initial read_api asyncio.sleep(2)")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print("read_api whole asyncio.sleep(2)")

async def gather():
    await asyncio.gather(
        asyncio.create_task(read_file()),
        asyncio.create_task(read_api()))
        
asyncio.run(gather())
"""
initial read_file asyncio.sleep(2.1)
initial read_api asyncio.sleep(2)
!!! Wait a moment
read_file 1/2 asyncio.sleep(2)
read_api whole asyncio.sleep(2)
read_file 2/2 asyncio.sleep(0.1)
"""
```

`await` scope:

- javascript: After the method is executed, wait for the Promise to resolve

  - `await wait(2)` Just `wait(2)` inside is guaranteed to be synchronous (or wait)
- python: Suspend method for other methods to execute

  - `await asyncio.sleep(2)` Method `read_file` will release resources and suspend

> btw, javascript's `await/async` is just `Promise` syntactic sugar

Comment: Your JavaScript version of `wait` has a bug. `setTimeout()` is a callback-based API and not a promise-based one, so you have to convert it to promise-based if you want to use it with promises, which your code isn't doing properly. Try this instead: `const wait = s => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, s * 1000));`